# Lagging in a data.table in R which is time series panel data

Tags: r, data.table

I was trying to use lag and data table notation to lag the variables, so that it is fastest. 
This is how I was trying to do it,

```
head(DT)
setkey(DT,code,year)
```

The output is

```
     code year pt_N_1y ws_country close is_msci
1: 130104 2003       0     ISRAEL     0       0     
2: 130104 2004       0     ISRAEL     0       0   
3: 130104 2005       0     ISRAEL     0       0    
4: 130104 2006       0     ISRAEL     0       0    
5: 130104 2007       0     ISRAEL     0       0    
6: 130104 2008       0     ISRAEL     0       0
```

```
DT[,L1_is_msci:=.SD[lag(is_msci,1)],by=code]
```

This gives 50 warnings and gives all `NA`'s.
Isn't `.SD` supposed to subset the data by "code" and apply the function `lag(is_msci, 1)`.
I would ideally like a 1 line function to do the lags and would like to work with `base` functions and data table notation as it is the most optimal while dealing with huge datasets without installing many packages. Is it possible?

What I want to achieve is

```
     code year pt_N_1y ws_country close is_msci L1_is_msci
1: 130104 2003       0     ISRAEL     0       0    NA 
2: 130104 2004       0     ISRAEL     0       0    0
3: 130104 2005       0     ISRAEL     0       0    0
4: 130104 2006       0     ISRAEL     0       0    0
5: 130104 2007       0     ISRAEL     0       0    0
6: 130104 2008       0     ISRAEL     0       0    0
```

Comment: Do you want `.SD[,lag(is_msci,1)]`?

Comment: No, this does not lag the series, I want NA's to appear at the first lag when there is no previous observation. This done by groups.

Comment: `DT[, L1_is_msci := lag(is_msci, 1), by = code]`?

Comment: No, lag gives a 0 to the missing variable, I want an NA. How can I do so?

Comment: @Arun, I have updated the question, when I did what eddi asked me to do, it just produced the same column as is_msci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please provide a [**reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) - one from which we can just copy/paste the code to get the data.

I'm not sure which function you're using for `lag` - you don't show it. The base function `lag` (from `stats`) seems to do something different. If you're using that, no wonder your results aren't what you expect. It's quite easy to test the function you're using:

```
# base function from package stats
lag(1:5, k=1L)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# attr(,"tsp")
# [1] 0 4 1
```

Obviously not what we want. So, let's write our own function:

```
lag <- function(x, n)
    if (n == 0) x else c(rep.int(NA, n), head(x, -n))

# test it
lag(1:5, 0)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

lag(1:5, 2)
# [1] NA NA  1  2  3
```

Now, you an apply @eddi's code:

```
DT[, L1_is_msci := lag(is_msci, 1L), by = code]
#      code year pt_N_1y ws_country close is_msci L1_is_msci
# 1: 130104 2003       0     ISRAEL     0       0         NA
# 2: 130104 2004       0     ISRAEL     0       0          0
# 3: 130104 2005       0     ISRAEL     0       0          0
# 4: 130104 2006       0     ISRAEL     0       0          0
# 5: 130104 2007       0     ISRAEL     0       0          0
# 6: 130104 2008       0     ISRAEL     0       0          0
```

HTH